# Cannot convert DataRow to titlesDataRow

Tags: c#, ado.net

I want to convert a DataRow into a titlesRow but i am having troubles to convert it, how i can do it?

```
private koianimeDataSet.titlesRow titlesRow;
DataTable dt = ta.GetDataByViews();
titlesRow = dt.Rows[0];
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2sO1.jpg)

Comment: What is `koianimeDataSet.titlesRow`?

Comment: What's `titlesRow`? Why do you expect to be able to implicitly convert a `DataRow` to a `titlesRow`?

Comment: Note: for most applications, `DataTable` is a bad solution to a very common need.

Comment: i have a custom user control that use an image from my database that is at the titlesRow

Comment: You need to [edit] your question and add the definition of `titlesRow`

Comment: the problem is that i cannot define it so i can't acces to his options

Comment: If you have a strongly typed `DataRow` you also have a stringly typed `DataTable`, `DataSet` and `TableAdapter`. Use the adapter to fill that `DataTable`. Then it's first row will be of type `koianimeDataSet.titlesRow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it: `koianimeDataSet.titlesRow` is the specific row subclass of a "typed dataset", i.e. `titlesRow : DataRow`. Now: if this is correct, **and if** `GetDataByViews` is *making use of the typed dataset*, then you should be able to just cast it:

```
titlesRow = (koianimeDataSet.titlesRow)dt.Rows[0];
```

If this works, then you should also check whether `GetDataByViews` could just return the typed datatable. It might actually already do this, so it *could* also be the case that:

```
var dt = ta.GetDataByViews();
```

fixes everything, by picking up the right table type.

---

If `GetDataByViews` *doesn't* make use of the typed dataset, then it will be a much bigger job. Frankly, before fixing that, I'd sooner challenge the assumption that `DataSet` (typed or otherwise) should be used *at all* here. In most ways: datasets are redundant compared to more modern class typed data access APIs.